# Spring Tool Suite 4 for Windows 32bit

Tags: spring-tools-4

I downloaded and unzip the Spring Tools 4 but i encounter an error "This app can't run on you PC. To find a version of your PC, check with the software publisher."

Is there a specific installer for Windows 32 bit?

Thanks,

CESAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying Eclipse platform removed support for 32bit Windows a while ago, so unfortunately I don't see a way to get this up and running on a 32bit Windows machine.

As an alternative, you might want to take a look at Visual Studio Code, which has an installer for 32bit Windows and you can get pretty good Java and Spring support for it.